# Sidebar going beyond screen on resize

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, sidebar

I have an HTML page with a sidebar. The sidebar is shown when i click 'Upload Data' button. When I resize the window, the sidebar's header (random portion from top) goes beyond the screen and the only way to retrieve is to refresh the page to start fresh. I need a solution for keeping the sidebar inside the window.

Initial body image

[image]

After resizing

[image]

HTML CODE

HEAD

```
<title>Index</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" href="https://www.pngkit.com/png/full/327-3270091_demographic-icon-sign.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/sidebar_style_final.css') }}">
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/js/solid.js" integrity="sha384-tzzSw1/Vo+0N5UhStP3bvwWPq+uvzCMfrN1fEFe+xBmv1C/AtVX5K0uZtmcHitFZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/js/fontawesome.js" integrity="sha384-6OIrr52G08NpOFSZdxxz1xdNSndlD4vdcf/q2myIUVO0VsqaGHJsB0RaBE01VTOY" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/3.1.5/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        .fa {
            margin-left: -8px;
            margin-right: 8px;
        }
        .bs-example {
            margin: 20px;
        }
        html{
            margin:0;
            height:100%;
        }

    </style>
```

sidebar_style_final.css

```
@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,500,600,700";
body {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

p {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 1.7em;
    color: #999;
}

a,
a:hover,
a:focus {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

.navbar {
    padding: 15px 10px;
    background: #fff;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.navbar-btn {
    box-shadow: none;
    outline: none !important;
    border: none;
}

.line {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #ddd;
    margin: 40px 0;
}

/* ---------------------------------------------------
    SIDEBAR STYLE
----------------------------------------------------- */

#sidebar {
    width: 450px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: -450px;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 999;
    background: #ffffff;
    color: #r45;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    overflow: auto;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

#sidebar.active {
    right: 0;
}

#dismiss {
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    line-height: 35px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #7386D5;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

#dismiss:hover {
    background: #fff;
    color: #7386D5;
}

.overlay {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    z-index: 998;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.overlay.active {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
}

#sidebar .sidebar-header {
    padding: 20px;
    background: #6d7fcc;
}

#sidebar ul.components {
    padding: 20px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #47748b;
}

#sidebar ul p {
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
}

#sidebar ul li a {
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    display: block;
}

#sidebar ul li a:hover {
    color: #7386D5;
    background: #fff;
}

#sidebar ul li.active>a,
a[aria-expanded="true"] {
    color: #fff;
    background: #6d7fcc;
}

a[data-toggle="collapse"] {
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown-toggle::after {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 20px;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

ul ul a {
    font-size: 0.9em !important;
    padding-left: 30px !important;
    background: #6d7fcc;
}

ul.CTAs {
    padding: 20px;
}

ul.CTAs a {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0.9em !important;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

a.download {
    background: #fff;
    color: #7386D5;
}

a.article,
a.article:hover {
    background: #6d7fcc !important;
    color: #fff !important;
}

/* ---------------------------------------------------
    CONTENT STYLE
----------------------------------------------------- */

#content {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    min-height: 100vh;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

BODY

```
<body onload="start_nav()" onresize="change_sidebar()">
<div class="grey_bound" id="grey_bound"></div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <!-- Sidebar  -->
    <div id="sidebar">
        <div id="dismiss" style="left: 30px; top: 20px;" onclick="hide_grey_bound()">
            <i class="fas fa-arrow-right" onclick="hide_grey_bound()"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="sidebar-header" align="right">
            <h3>Upload new data</h3>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <div class="bs-example" style="width:400px;position:relative;left:10px;">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#shp_files" class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" id='new_tab'>Shape Files</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#cate_csv" class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab">Category Files</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="tab-content" id="tab_content" style="height: 600px; overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: hidden;">
                SIDEBAR CONTENT
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
    <!-- Page Content  -->
    <div id="content">
        <button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" class="btn btn-info" style="position: relative;float: right;right: 10px;" onclick="function show_grey_bound() { document.getElementById('grey_bound').style.display = 'block'; }
        show_grey_bound()">
            <i class="fas fa-caret-square-up"></i>
            <span>Upload Data</span>
        </button>
    </div>
    
</div>
</body>
```

SCRIPT

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#sidebar").mCustomScrollbar({
            theme: "minimal"
        });

        $('#dismiss, .overlay').on('click', function () {
            $('#sidebar').removeClass('active');
            $('.overlay').removeClass('active');
        });

        $('#sidebarCollapse').on('click', function () {
            $('#sidebar').addClass('active');
            $('.overlay').addClass('active');
            $('.collapse.in').toggleClass('in');
            $('a[aria-expanded=true]').attr('aria-expanded', 'false');
        });
    });
```

I have already tried

- setting document.getELementById('sidebar').scrollTop = 0 onresize of
  body.
- changing the top of the sidebar onresize.
- to give margin-top to 0.

Can anyone help me with this. Like I said, I need the side bar to stay inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the height in your Sidebar content div

```
            <div class="tab-content" id="tab_content" style="overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: hidden;">
                SIDEBAR CONTENT
            </div>
```

Comment: you also need to set this onload of body
document.getElementById('sidebar').style.height = window.outerHeight.toString() + 'px';